# What db is suitable for implementing the like functionality?

Tags: database, react-native, nosql

I want to implement the like functionality in my app and im searching for a good solution when it comes to the database. Until now I looked at Firebase, and it seems it could the job when using sharding. As I am a beginner with DBs I thought of asking you.
What do you think?

Maybe AWS or something else has something suitable for this use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all I will choose the same DB as you are using to save users data.

If you don't have anyone yet, I will recommend you go with Firebase, it can handle your users sessions, social logins, databases and also you can implement a solution for the like functionality.

Comment: Yes, I am using Firebase for that. Could you give me some tips where to look to implement this functionality in Firebase?

Comment: Answer to my own question above: analytics.

Answer (score 0):

If your already using firebase, the realtime database should be best practice. Theres even an example with likes in the firebase rtDb Docs for web. But of course you should use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/).

Comment: Thanks mate! Looking into it now. One question though: what is the advantage of using react-native-firebase over just firebase?

Comment: Normal Firebase is not made for react-native. Using it will only work for the simplest tasks, but fail in more complex ones. If I remember it right the realtime database throws connection errors when trying to use it in react-native. Also your progress will be faster since there is way more help and tutorials for firebase on react-native with react-native-firebase package.